# Showing source code in a WordPress blog post

Tags: wordpress

According to this WordPress link:

https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/

I should be able to post source code.

Yet, look at the bottom of this blog post, before the horizontal line:

http://blog.publictalksoftware.co.uk/2017/10/10/changes-to-the-midweek-editor-from-january-2018/

It is not working. How do I fix this?

This is what is in the table cell:

```
We don't need to display the <strong>Student</strong>/<strong>Assistant </strong>labels when we are discussing a <strong>sample conversation video</strong>. Changes are required in your script.

I will make the following change to all default S-140 scripts for us. However, if you are using a customized S-140 script then you will need to replicate the same changes:

[code language="xml", firstline="318", highlight="330,331,332,333,334,335,341,342"]
  <xsl:template match="StudentItem">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Time" mode="End"/>
      <td class="cellTheme">
        <span class="bulletAYFM">&#8226;</span>
        <span class="textTheme">
          <xsl:value-of select="Type"/>
        </span>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Time" mode="Duration"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Material"/>
      </td>
      <td class="cellPosition">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@IsSampleVideo=1">
            <!--We need an empty cell-->
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="//Labels/Student"/>
            <xsl:if test="@IsTalk=0">
              <br/>
              <xsl:value-of select="//Labels/Assistant"/>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </td>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Students"/>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
[/code]
```

But even if I just put it in the main post outside of a table, doesn't render right.

I have had to remove the above attempted code from the post as it was not rendering right and just have the image of the code. I am open to proposals for doing what I wanted. I liked the advertised shortcode because I could specify line numbers and highlight lines. Confused.

Comment: Can you post the full snippet with the opening and closing shortcode?

Comment: @kawnah Updated.

Comment: @kawnah I added a image of the code to show what I was expecting. Is it not possible to show code? The article implied I could.

Comment: The first article is about wordpress.com and it looks like your website is not hosted by wordpress.com

Comment: @mmm Correct. My site is hosted with one.com.

Comment: you can try this plugin : https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/

Comment: @mmm That is not what I want I am afraid. That is not designed to display code in a blog post. It is more like code reuse.

Comment: @I have changed to CodeColorer. That works if my code is not in a table cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortcode that you have used is for hosted WordPress.com blogs. Yours is a self-hosted WordPress website so you'll need to download a plugin to get this to work.

Details of the plugin are provided on the page that you linked to, at the bottom, under 'Credits' (copied below).

"[Alex Gorbatchev’s SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter) project was used in the implementation of this feature. If you are a [WordPress.org](http://support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/) user and would like to use this feature on your self-hosted blog, it is available as [a plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/)."

Comment: That plugin is no longer being maintained. But thanks for the answer. I am using CodeColorer.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle - I hadn't noticed that but thanks for accepting my answer ;-) I've always used WP-GeSHi-Highlight - https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-geshi-highlight/